# get MailChimp response with Java

Tags: java, rest, get, mailchimp

I want to use the MailChimp api to add a subscriber. As a start, want to read from one of the REST I'm trying to get a response back from the MailChimp api.

I seem to be doing the authorization correctly as I'm getting status 200, but for some reason, I am not getting the response.

Here is the code so far:

```
public void doPostAction() throws IOException{

    // BASIC Authentication
    String name = "user";
    String password = apikey;
    String authString = name + ":" + password;

    byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
    String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);

    URL urlConnector = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnector.openConnection();
    httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    httpConnection.setDoInput(true);
    httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);

    InputStream is = httpConnection.getInputStream();

    // check status
    System.out.println("DoPost: status: " + httpConnection.getResponseCode());

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"));

    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
    System.out.println("DoPost response: \n" + line);
    br.close(); 
}
```

Looking at the MailChimp playground, it seems like I'm missing out on a lot...

[image]

How do I get the response?

****/ EDIT /****
If anyone's looking at the above code, the output should be:

```
System.out.println("DoPost response: \n" + sb);  // not line
```

Comment: Try debugging it line by line. Make sure URL is correct with proper headers

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya Hi and thanks for your comment. I wonder if you have ever done this or something similar with Java and a REST api?
If so, could you give me an working example on a REST service?

Comment: I have done this many times but not with MailChimp but with other services. Try to get the response through Postman or other clients to make sure it is working before getting started in Java

Answer (score 0):

OK, the above code works. Basic error.

I was examining the line variable when it was null, not the response...

When I change to:

```
System.out.println("DoPost response: \n" + line);  // not line
System.out.println("DoPost response: \n" + sb);  // but sb StringBuilder
```

...it works.